# What do the (high) values in a controllability matrix mean?

Tags: matrices, vectors, control-theory, linear-control, steady-state

Consider a linear state space system $ \dot{x} = Ax + B$, with $x$ being a vector of state variables, and $A$ and $B$ being known matrices.

I checked the controllability matrix of the system $Co = [B \; AB \; A^2B \dots A^{n-1}B]$ via a MATLAB function ($rank(ctrb(A,B))$), and got a full rank matrix and thus, the system is controllable.

However, the matrix $Co$ has values that range from $-8.0220e+05$ until $1.0672e+06$, which seems quite extreme, as my $x$ values lie in the range of $0-100$.

My question is then:
What do these high values in a controllability matrix mean, and should I worry about these values being this far from the range of x values?

Comment: What are the absolute values of the eigenvalues of $A$? Namely, I suspect that the extreme values in the controllability matrix is in its last (or last few) column(s), is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is true and is because of the $[B AB A^2B....A^(n-1)B]$ structure of the controllability matrix.  With $n=6$, the last two eigenvalues of $A$ are $~ -12$, where the first four are $0$ or close to $0$.

Comment: Excuse me, seems my formatting was wrong. I meant $[B \; AB \; A^2B....A^{n-1}B]$, and two eigenvalues **around** $-12$.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of your system and the magnitude of the entries, the controllability matrix may be ill-conditioned and computing its rank will be prone to numerical errors. In other words, this approach should sometimes be avoided. Issues especially arise when some entries are very close to 0. High values may be problematic when much smaller values are also present, which may lead to numerical problems.

In your example, no entry is very close to zero but there is a quite big gap between entries, so I would be careful. Without more details on the matrices $A$ and $B$ you consider, it is difficult to say much more.

More stable approaches are those using the PBH-test or through the calculation of the  controllability Gramian.

Comment: The controllability Gramian might also not be well behaved. Namely, if $A$ isn't a Hurwitz matrix then it might blow up. One can also use the finite instead of infinite horizon controllability Gramian to determine whether a system is controllable or not.

Comment: That's true but it can be fixed by computing the controllability matrix of $A-\lambda I$ for some sufficiently large $\lambda$ that makes $A-\lambda I$ Hurwitz stable. The controllability of $(A,B)$ is equivalent of that of $(A-\lambda I,B)$.

Comment: My system is of size $n=6$, but the question can be considered generally. I think the high values are logical due to the structure of $Co$ being that of $[B \; AB \; A^2B....A^{n-1}B]$, meaning higher values on the last columns of the matrix. I never heard of the PBH-test, nor the controllability Gramian so I will check that out, thanks!